# Access razor page Model from parent abstract page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a base abstract class for my razor pages like this:

```
public abstract class NGBaseRazorPage : Page
{
    protected NGBaseRazorPage()
    {

    }

    public Guid PageId { get; } = Guid.NewGuid();
}
```

and I have a base PageModel like this:

```
public abstract class NGBasePageModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public Guid PageId { get; }
}
```

Now I want to access the PageModel from NGBaseRazorPage on a razor page that inherited from NGBaseRazorPage like this.

```
@page "/TestPage"
@inherits NGBaseRazorPage
@model SomeAwesomePageModel // Already inherrited from NGBasePageModel.
{
}
```

FYI: My project type is ASP .NET Core and it is based on .NET 7.0.
Also, I shared a minimal respos to demonstrate what I want here on Github

[**GitHub Repository**](https://github.com/NGame1/AspPageIdSampleRepos)

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide a lot more information about what you're trying to do - in particular, what project type you're using.
If you can provide a minimal reproducible example, including both the C# code and the project file, 
we're much more likely to be able to help you.

Comment: Project type is ASP .NET Core (.NET 7.0) and I want to add a PageId to my pages that it automatically set in PageModels. I want to do this because I'm writing some framework-like project and I need to know wich page is actually sending data to the backend. That's a bit dificult to tell, But think we have a tabbed view and you opened one page in 2 or 3 different tabs. And you are posting some data to a controller. I can add this id in every page where it is needed but such things happening much and I want to handle it one time if it is possible. I will generate a minimal repo soon. @QingGuo

Comment: Hi There again @QingGuo, I've created a sample repos to share what I exactyl want with you. https://github.com/NGame1/AspPageIdSampleRepos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add the below code in the form in Index to pass the  PageId to post method:

```
<input name="PageId" type="hidden" value="@PageId"  />
```

The full form like:

```
<form method="post">

    <div>
        <label>This is the page id</label>
        <br />
        <label type="text">@PageId</label>
    </div>
    <input name="PageId" type="hidden" value="@PageId"  />

    <div>
        <button type="submit">Post</button>
    </div>

</form>
```

result:

[image]

Comment: I know that I can pass it in a hidden input manually. Isn't it possible to somehow do that BaseRazorPage or BasePageModel?

Comment: Hi @AliNGame ,  pass it in a hidden input manually is the simplest way, the PageId  from BasePageModel, you need to set the value for it. If you want to get the PageId BaseRazorPage, you need to do a lot of changes.